# Has the idea of generalizing the codomain of a metric been seriously considered?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

The [long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29) is much longer than $\mathbb{R}$, and indeed many chains have this property. Thus, since metrics are usually assumed to be real-valued, this can be understood as an assumption that point-to-point distances are "short" in some sense.

Presumably, this has a variety of benefits. For example, every metrizable space is [paracompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space), a smallness condition that apparently follows from the shortness of $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I also think it has some drawbacks. There are many, *many* spaces that simply aren't metrizable. So I think that if we generalize the notion of a metric $d$ such that the codomain needn't be $\mathbb{R},$ this would make a larger class of spaces metrizable.

**Reference request.** Has the idea of generalizing the codomain of a metric been seriously considered? If so, a link or reference would be appreciated.

*Remark*. Its true that $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique Dedekind-complete linearly ordered field. So this would seem to put a kink in the idea. However, I think that $\mathbb{R}$ has much more structure than we really need to do metric space theory. In particular, every real number $x$ has an additive inverse $-x,$ and so long as $x$ is non-zero it has a multiplicative inverse $x^{-1}$. I don't think either of these properties are truly necessarily for the codomain of a metric.

Comment: paracompactness of metrizable spaces is not so much a consequence of the shortness of $\mathbb R$, as much as it is a consequence of it being separable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a short note just recently on the precise question you are asking: [A note on the metrizability of spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4940).

The short answer is, yes, it was done and is very elegant and useful. My note is based on Flagg's work "quantales and continuity spaces".

Comment: It has been done in other ways, some of which are far more attractive from a purely topological point of view.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott references please?

Comment: and @BrianM.Scott if you have the time and if you feel like commenting on my note, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It’s been way too long since I looked at them for me to be able to come up with references; you could look for $\omega_\mu$-metrizable spaces and, more generally, linearly uniformizable spaces, with generalized metrics taking values in an ordered Abelian group. // I’m not a good person to comment on the note, I’m afraid: category theory and I don’t get along at all well.

Comment: ok @BrianM.Scott, thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, far more attractive than the usual "codomain = $\mathbb{R}$" approach, or far more attractive than Flagg's approach? Having spent the last half hour reading Flagg's stuff, I have to say it looks pretty elegant.

Answer (score 1):

For concrete examples, if you have any ordered field, you can rewrite its order topology in terms of its "self-metric". In the largest (in some sense, most general) case, this [was done for the surreals](http://www.ithaca.edu/hs/depts/math/docs/capstone/2013/lippitt.pdf). Unfortunately, this doesn't really lead anywhere useful because of your remark: Everything bigger than the reals has gaps (and subfields of the reals have "holes":$\mathbb Q$-cauchy sequences that don't converge).

Comment: The requirement that whatever the codomain of a metric function should be, it should at least be a field is a strange one. Very little of the field structure of $\mathbb R$ is ever used in metric considerations. If one does not insist on having a field, but rather concentrates on the lattice properties one really needs, then every space is metrizable.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I did not mean to imply that it was a good requirement, merely a source of a convenient class of examples one could consider, and that was considered.